# What's the area of this shaded square?

Tags: geometry, contest-math

This is a square with a side length of 3 (and therefore with area 9).

[image: square with smaller grey square]

**What's the area of the shaded square?** I can see these four triangles with area $\frac{3}{2}$:

[image: triangles]

The annoying matter are those overlapping parts. I've tried to take those parts and connect them into a square, but it just results in a shape that's similar to the original square but with area 1.

[image: tiny square]

Also, in general, are there any tricks to solving these problems, where there are overlapping regions? I seem to see these a lot, but I keep getting stuck on them.

Comment: I smell a lot of Pythagoras

Comment: @Dstarred Oh yeah, that might work. I could use similar triangles and Pythagoras to do it. Seems messy though, would there be a more satisfying and intuitive way?

Comment: Using similar triangles try to find the ratio of the legs of the small top-right right triangle. Then use the Pythagoras Theorem to determine those lengths. Then move to the hypothenuse of the large top triangle to find the side length of the square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Draw other lines to complete the figure as follows:

[image]

Then notice that the regions with the same number form a square.

You have $10$ squares, so the area of each square is $\frac{9}{10}$. The area you are looking for is formed by four of these squares: $4\times \frac{9}{10} = \frac{18}{5}$

Comment: That is very nice!

Comment: Very satisfying solution, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

$\triangle DBA$ and $\triangle ABC$ are similar; and $BC=\sqrt 10$, so their sides are in the ratio $\rho=\dfrac{AB}{BC}=\dfrac{3}{\sqrt 10}$.

Therefore their areas are in the ration $\rho^2=\frac{9}{10}$. And the area of $\triangle ABC$ is $\frac32$.

Hence the area of $\triangle DBA$ is...

Comment: I'm amazed at the size of your triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Pythagorean Theorem shows that the hypotenuse of each of the overlapping right triangles has length $\sqrt{10}.$

Let's consider the right triangles of overlap, which have hypotenuses of length $1,$ and small and large legs of lengths $l$ and $L,$ respectively, say. Since the triangles of overlap are readily similar to the larger ones, then we know $$l=\frac{l}{1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}=\frac{1}{10}\sqrt{10}$$ and $$L=\frac{L}{1}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}=\frac{3}{10}\sqrt{10}.$$

If $S$ is the side length of the shaded square, then we see that $\sqrt{10}=l+S+L,$ so $$S=\sqrt{10}-l-L=\sqrt{10}-\frac{4}{10}\sqrt{10}=\frac{6}{10}\sqrt{10}=\frac{6}{\sqrt{10}}.$$ Therefore, the area of the shaded square is $\frac{36}{10}=\frac{18}{5}.$

Answer (score 0):

Look at the three pieces at the bottom of the square. They form a right-angled triangle with sides $1$ and $3$. Therefore the angle at the bottom left of the triangle is given by $\tan(\phi) = 1/3$ or $\phi = \arctan(1/3)$.

Consider the same triangle, minus the small upright triangle on the right. The two remaining parts form another right-angled triangle with hypothenusa $3$. The two short sides are equal to $3\cos(\phi)$ and $3\sin(\phi)$. Hence its surface area is equal to $(9/2)\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi)$. From $\tan(\phi) = 1/3$ we obtain $\sin(\phi) = 1/\sqrt{10}$ and $\cos(\phi) = 3/\sqrt{10}$. So the area is equal to $27/20$

Now the total area of the figure is $9$, and there are $4$ triangles (see previous paragraph), hence the area of the central square is equal to $9 -18\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi) = 9-27/5 = 18/5$.